# Can I add folder shortcuts to the start search

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I have a a few folders that I use the most, these folders are already pinned to the task bar, added to the desktop and to the left bar in the explorer.

But I want to add these folders to the start menu **search**.
I want that when I press `win` and type 'localhost' that my localhost folder shortcut pops up.
I tried adding folder shortcuts to `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
It didn't work. :(

Anybody got any ideas? thnx

Comment: Do the folders not show up in the `Documents` section of the search?

Comment: I've disabled the index of the public folder, I don't want the content of those folders to show up, just the folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this.

I went to `configuration`-> `indexoptions`. There I added only the a folder which has all the schortcuts I need, and the startmenu folder itself.
After that in the `advance` tab I added `.ink` to the file types. Now it also indexes shortcuts.

Works like a charm.